# add click event to Jquery UI accordian Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

When you create a Jquery UI accordian you get a bunch of headers, that when you click them a div opens. However, I would like to preform an additional action upon clicking the header.

How do i do this?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have both of the HTML statements provided in the same page, then your HTML is invalid as IDs are suppose to be unique.  If not please clarify.

Comment: No, those were two different attempts. I was making another stupid mistake. I posted the correct answer below. Thanks anyways, sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
$("#CreateNewUserHeader").click(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

**html**

```
<h3 id = "CreateNewUserHeader"><a >Create New User</a></h3>
<div>some stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your code in `ready` handler:

```
$(function(){
  $("#CreateNewUserHeader").click(function() {
    alert("test");
  });
});
```

Also make sure that you do not assign ***same id*** to more than one elements.

Comment: My code was working, it was a different part that was screwing it up. Sorry, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3):

What I've done when I needed to do this in the past was something like this:

```
$('#accordion h3 a').bind('click', function (e) {
  // bind to the the header / anchor clicks
  if (!condition) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

Comment: ya this is what I ended up doing, except I wanted the default action, and I don't have an issue with the click propagating. I wantted an additional action.

Answer (score 2):

You guys should read the documentation, there is an event handler that will do it all for you.

https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
  activate: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```