# Rails with turbolinks and an accordion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui-accordion, turbolinks

I have this JQuery UI accordion that acts as a sidebar of sorts. I want to have an additional action for the section click event and I've got this working based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492467/add-click-event-to-jquery-ui-accordian-header) SO response with:

```
$(".sidebar_category").click(function(event) {
  // the section contains a span and my anchor; only go when
  // the click is  over the anchor
  if (event.target.href !== undefined) {
    window.location = event.target.href;
  }
});
```

Now ... that works, but not the same way clicking on the other links works because by using turbolinks an AJAX switcheroo is performed that I would like to emulate.

Needles to say that [simulating a click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426617/simulate-a-click-on-a-link-with-javascript) doesn't do the trick. I'm expecting something like [this](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/converting-links-ajax-links):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('a').bind('click',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.get(this.href,{},function(response){ 
               $('#response').html(response)
            })  
         })
        });
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <li><a href="response.html"/>Response</a>
    <div id="response"></div>
</body>
```

but rails style. So how does one follow a link turbolinks style?

PS: my stripped gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-sass-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-themes'
gem 'turbolinks'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Turbolinks is using to make our applications appear faster to the user by using JavaScript to replace the HTML body of new pages instead of relying on a full page load. Inside the head tag code doesn't load in all pages. So, put inside the body tag

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('a').bind('click',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.get(this.href,{},function(response){ 
               $('#response').html(response)
            })  
         })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I understand this. I was asking about something "rails style", maybe a method of sorts.